# How and why do I know the song Луди жаби?

Tags: history

I'm gonna win the prize for the most weird question ever? Maybe.

I've recently moved to Bulgaria from Italy, and a bunch of weeks ago on TV I heard a song, Луди жаби from the band Джанго Зе. (trad: Ludi Jabi from the band Jango Ze)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssO8JARyViA

Problem is: I already knew this song by memory. Which doesn't seems to make a lot of sense, apparently, 'cause I've been before in Bulgaria only for a couple days, and I can't find a trace of this song ever crossing the border to Italy, but maybe I don't know how to search for it.

So, aside from personal opinions and conjectures, the real question is: does anyone know if this song has ever been famous/used/aired/covered outside Bulgaria?

Comment: I've never been in Bulgaria, and the riff and song make me think I've heard it before.  Maybe it's very like some other song.  I'd think if the song echoes another one , that song would be another  European song from France / Spain / Italy, but just guessing here.

Comment: I don't even speak Bulgarian, but the video seems to be using hypnotical tactics to make its music sound like it's familiar...